# Detect keyboard navigation in angular material mat-selection-list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to make some actions When navigating between items **using keyboard arrows**.

Is there any event should i implemented?
The selectionChange is fired by clicking ENTER but i want to activate the function while navigating by arrows.

```
<mat-selection-list #list (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event, list.selectedOptions)">
  <mat-list-option (mouseenter)="showEditIcon(true, i)" (mouseleave)="showEditIcon(false, i)"
                   *ngFor="let lotItem of lotList; let i = index;"
                   (click)="showLotDetails(lotItem, i)"
                   [value]='lotItem'>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **`keydown`** keyboard event on your **`mat-selection-list`** in order to call your **`selectionChange()`** method. You'll need to add both **`(keydown.arrowup)`** and **`(keydown.arrowdown)`** event handlers.

```
<mat-selection-list #list 
       (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event, list.selectedOptions)"
       (keydown.arrowup)="selectionChange($event)" 
       (keydown.arrowdown)="selectionChange($event)">

    <mat-list-option (mouseenter)="showEditIcon(true, i)" (mouseleave)="showEditIcon(false, i)"
                   *ngFor="let lotItem of lotList; let i = index;"
                   (click)="showLotDetails(lotItem, i)"
                   [value]='lotItem'>
```

Here is a [**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eg2yob?file=app/list-selection-example.html).

Comment: Great but the event is the keyboard event - how can i get the selected\focus items details?

Comment: Add this: **`<mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" #opt (keydown)="selected = opt">`** - see the updated demo.

Comment: The keyboard navigation always selects the previous shoe. Because the keyboard event fires before setting the selected MatListOption. Any fix for that?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Faisal! I've used your solution for <mat-tree-node (keydown.space)="$event.preventDefault()"> and it worked like a magic!! I was looking for this solution for a long time...